# What is the Nested Animation time lines workaround?

Tags: animation

**File 1:**

- I create a blender file Name: Amenities
- And i create 2 Animations

  - **Animation 1** Tap scaling from 0 to 1 to appear and 1 to 0 to disappear. Between frames 1-100.
  - **Animation 2** Water flowing down from a tap. Between frames 1-100. Water flows as particle animation (baked).
- I group tap and water particle effect emitter as **Amenities_Tap**

**File 2:**

I have Some animation existing from frame 1 to frame 500. And i want to **LINK** *Amenities_Tap* group. And animation at frame 500.

**PROBLEM 1** The animation of linked group plays between frame 1-100. But how do i make it play from frame 500?

**How i am doing** I am going to **File 1** and offsetting animation to play between frames 500-600. And i come back to **File 2** and update linked blend file and it works.

**PROBLEM 2** It is becoming tedious to tweak animation timing in **File 2**

**NOTE:**

- As Camera movement is continuous and part of File 2. So i cant isolate this and render separate and composite.
- Even if i rig the Amenities, and LINK RIG and action file into FILE 2 and proxy it and apply action file. The particle animation plays only between frame 1 and 100.